# Accessing an instance variable site-wide for navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

I am a rails newbie writing my first App and I am having a hard time figuring out exactly how views work. I am just trying to write a simple navigation menu that dynamically grabs the list of all my "Services" and then lists the sub-catagories "Service Offerings" under those. This navigation needs to show up on every page in my App.

I tried the following just to test if I could pull the data.

```
#application_helper.rb

  def service_list
   ServiceOffering.find(1)
  end

#application.html.erb

 <%= service_list.name %>
 <%= yield %>
```

This works but I read that I should not put that sort of thing in the application_helper. I moved it to the application_controller.rb but it did not work there. I am really confused about this whole thing. Obviously, I have instance variables for @service_offering in my CRUD but they all mean different things depending on the action. I just want to define one that I can access from anywhere. I have watched and read a lot of tutorials in the past few weeks but hardly any of them touch on application wide stuff like this. I would really appreciate an easy to understand explanation of how to handle things of this nature. Thank you!

Comment: Try adding .first to the find command: ServiceOffering.find(1).first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set it up in the application controller you have a couple options:

you could set it up with a helper method so

```
#application_controller.rb

helper_method :service_list

def service_list
  ServiceOffering.find(1)
end
```

or you could set it up with a hook and put it into a special instance variable that will not conflict with the other ones that you have

```
#application_controller.rb

before_filter :service_list

def service_list
  @special_service_offerice = ServiceOffering.find(1)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that is what I needed. I believe I was a bit confused about "helpers" vs. "helper_methods". In general, am I taking the correct approach to what I am trying to do i.e. building a site-wide navigation?

Comment: I would say the helper_method is the correct approach. I would use helper_methods for things that are static throughout the app, but may need to be accessed in the controllers. I'd use a before_filter is it needed to be accessible throughout the app, but could change from controller to controller (i.e. maybe breadcrumb links on pages)